# React передача данных между компонентами

Tags: reactjs

Я пытаюсь реализовать функционал, когда пользователь логинится в дочернем элементе,  в родительский передавалось значение. Как вызвать функцию без прорисовки кнопки в дочернем элементе ?

Родительский элемент

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isLogging: false
    };
    this.logInHandler = this.logInHandler.bind(this);
  }

  logInHandler() {
    this.setState({ isLogging: !this.state.isLogging });
  }



  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Layout>
          {/* <Route path='/' exact component={Logging} /> */}
          <Route path='/' exact component={() => <Logging logInHandler={this.state.logInHandler} />} />
          { this.state.isLogging ?
            <Route path='/user_desk' exact component={UserMain} />
          : null }
```

Дочерний элемент

```
class Logging extends Component{


    loginHandler(e) {
        const element = document.getElementById("redirect");
        e.preventDefault();
        const us_name = document.getElementById("username").value;
        const us_email = document.getElementById("useremail").value;
        const us_pas = document.getElementById("userpass").value;
        const API_URL = '/rest_auth/login/';
        axios.post(API_URL, { username: us_name, password: us_pas, email: us_email}, {withCredentials: true})
        .then((response) => {
            if (response.status === 200 || response.status === '200' ) {
                console.log(this.props); // тут выдаёт ошибку (ниже)
                window.location.href = '/user_desk';
            }
          }, (error) => {
            console.log('INVALID CRUDENTIOALS', error);
          });
    }
    render() {
        return(
            <div className='loggin-main min-vh-100 p-0'>
             {console.log(this.props)} // сдесь ошибки нету
            // далее вызывается функция loginHandler
```

Ошибка

> Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'props' of
> undefined

Как вызвать функцию родителя logInHandler в дочерней функции ?

Comment: Полагаю, при транспиляции теряется контекст

Comment: прошу прощения, что теряется ?

Comment: Попробуйте пример из [auth-workflow](https://reactrouter.com/web/example/auth-workflow).

Comment: @AjeetShah мне нужна именно в таком ключе. Может кто-то объяснить почему так получается ошибка ?

Comment: Попробуйте `<Logging logInHandler={this.logInHandler} />` и `loginHandler = (e) => { ... `